# How to compile for outdated kernel (2.4.5)

Tags: compilation, linux-kernel, cross-compiling

I'm working with a very peculiar environment: SH4 architecture, RedHat Linux, kernel 2.4.5.

I'm trying to write a graphic application using Xlib that can run in this environment.

I experimented long time ago with cross-compiling for SH4 architecture and it worked OK. However I never had to compile for a specific outdated kernel.

Set up a VM with linux mint, installed g++, cmake,

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //print output
    cout << "hello" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I run the compiler

```
g++ hello.cpp
```

And get a binary file "a.out".
I can execute the binary by typing "./a.out". It prints "hello".

However when I transfer "a.out" to the SH4 machine via FTP and try to run it I get:

```
bash: a.out: cannot execute binary file
```

This leads me to believe that the target computer doesn't understand the compiled binary.

Comment: And what is the question or problem you’re having?

Comment: "I experimented long time ago with cross-compiling for SH4 architecture and it worked OK." - Do the same in the given case. First of all, you need to compile not for the *version* of the Linux kernel, but for the specific **architecture** (SH4 in you case).